# Unable to Post List of Objects from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Having an issue passing a list of a Custom Object to my Controller

Here is the Model

```
public class UploadDocumentViewModel
{
    public string EncryptedApplicationId { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentViewModel> Documents { get; private set; }

    public UploadDocumentViewModel()
    {
        Documents = new List<DocumentViewModel>();
    }

}

public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public IFormFile DocumentFile { get; set; }
    public string DocumentDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the Form

```
<form asp-action="UploadDocuments" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="EncryptedApplicationId" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group mt-20">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Documents.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group mt-20">
            <input asp-for="Documents[i]" type="hidden" />
            <label asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentDescription" />
            <input asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentFile" />
        </div>
    }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-20">
        <a asp-action="Exit" asp-route-applicationId="@Model.EncryptedApplicationId" class="btn btn-info btn-primary btn-rounded text-left" style="position:relative;left:-1em;">Exit</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-success btn-rounded text-right" style="position:relative;right:-8em;">Continue  <i class="ti ti-angle-double-right" style="font-weight:bold;top:1px;right:-5px;position: relative;"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But in my Post method my `model.Documents` is always empty. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocuments(UploadDocumentViewModel model)
```

Comment: you need to make sure that the type attribute is correctly asigned.So `<input asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentFile" />` should be `<input asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentFile" type="file" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it required me to pass through the `DocumentDescription` tried different constructors on the view model but it always failed binding when there was no Description passed to the controller.

```
<form asp-action="UploadDocuments" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="EncryptedApplicationId" type="hidden" />
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Documents.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group mt-20">
            <input asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentDescription" type="hidden" />
            <label class="control-label">@Model.Documents[i].DocumentDescription</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Documents[i].DocumentFile" />
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group mt-20">
        <a asp-action="Exit" asp-route-applicationId="@Model.EncryptedApplicationId" class="btn btn-info btn-primary btn-rounded text-left" style="position:relative;left:-1em;">Exit</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-success btn-rounded text-right" style="position:relative;right:-8em;">Continue  <i class="ti ti-angle-double-right" style="font-weight:bold;top:1px;right:-5px;position: relative;"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `asp-for` attribute and use a valid `name` attribute. You do not need to provide the word `Model` to provide a Model.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Documents.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group mt-20">
        @* if you want to send the data in the DocumentFile property, just send it as a hidden *@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Documents[i].DocumentFile)       

        <label for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Documents[i].DocumentFile)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Documents[i].DocumentDescription)</label>

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Documents[i].DocumentFile)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it required me to add a `@Html.HiddenFor` on my DocumentDescription property